Python コラッツ予想のコード（再代入）について
pythonの勉強中（初心者）です。
ネットで「コラッツ予想」というものを見て、Pythonで書いてみました。
何度か試して、うまくいきましたが、１点疑問があります。
else以下のコードを再代入するか否かが成功or失敗のポイントだと体験しましたが、
再代入がポイントであれば、同様に、ifがtruthであった場合の
random_number //= 2

も、
random_number = random_number //= 2

になると思ったのですが、そう書くとエラーが出ます。
再代入するかしないか、その違いはなぜでしょうか？
教えていただけたら嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。
（便宜上、自然数は１から９９９までの整数としています）
〇成功例
import random

random_number = random.randint(1, 999)　# 1から999までの乱数を生成
print(f"発生した乱数: {random_number}")

count = 0

while random_number > 1:  #乱数が1以上であればループさせる

    if random_number % 2 == 0:  #random_numberが偶数であれば、
        random_number //= 2  #2で割る。//と2回繰り返すと、小数点以下略になる
    else:
        random_number = random_number *3 +1  #偶数でないなら、3倍して1を足し、再代入

    count += 1

    print(f"{count}回目",random_number)  #結果を表示する

×失敗例（奇数だと無限に表示されるので注意！）
import random

random_number = random.randint(1, 999)　# 1から999までの乱数を生成
print(f"発生した乱数: {random_number}")

while random_number > 1:  #乱数が1以上であればループさせる

    if random_number % 2 == 0:  #random_numberが偶数であれば、
        random_number //= 2  #2で割る。
    else:
        random_number *3 +1  #再代入していないからダメ！
        #奇数だとずーっと表示され続けるエラーが出る

    print(random_number)  #結果を表示する


//= という書き方がそもそも「計算結果を左辺の変数に代入し直す」という省略形な記法です。
以下2行の書き方は等価
a //= b
a = a // b

random_number //= 2 を冗長な書き方に直すなら以下のようになるはずです。
random_number = random_number //= 2   # NG
random_number = random_number // 2    # OK

失敗例での else の処理では random_number の値が変わらないので無限ループになるのは当然です。
参考:
代入演算子 | とほほの Python 入門
